# Install 16.04 on dell xps 13

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, 16.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell xps 13 9350 as well. I have followed the step from this link: [Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 8/10 in dual boot](http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/#).

But I don't see the screen of step 2.7 (the screen where it detects that you have Windows boot manager and ask you what type of install you want) Instead it goes directly to the next screen (where you are supposed to see all your partitions) but it show nothing.

I am a bit stuck right now. Any idea?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Can you please boot with the "Try Ubuntu" option and include the output of `sudo parted -l` and `sudo lsblk -l` and/or a screenshot of GParted?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Find below a screenshot with the output https://goo.gl/photos/ArWhxZgxbemovQTM7

Comment: For some reason Linux doesn't see any storage devices aside from the installation medium (probably some USB drive) even though the Dell XPS 13 is supposed to include an SSD. Can you please include the output of `sudo lshw -C storage -C disk` in your question.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(2016)) for this device:

> When the SATA-controller is set to "RAID On" in Bios, the hard disk (at least the SSD) is not recognized. Set to "Off" or "AHCI" before attempting to install Arch. If dual boot to Windows is intended, follow [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(2016)) to work around the "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" error.

The same goes for an Ubuntu install, most likely. Switch the SATA controller in BIOS to 'AHCI' or 'Off' before trying to install Ubuntu.

If this doesn't work alone, try `modprobe nvme` to load the necessary driver for the NVMe SSD.

Comment: Should it be switched back after installing?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but RAID for this laptop seems to be unnecessary. AHCI should do fine. My XPS 12 has AHCI only as well.

Comment: I just switched it back to `RAID` after installing ubuntu, and it stopped loading. Switching back to `AHCI` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble getting dual boot installed.

This worked for me http://www.rationaljava.com/2016/10/dell-xps13-dual-boot-windows-10-with.html