# Ubuntu Installation on Dell 15-7568

Tags: system-installation

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu on my Dell 15-7568 and am hitting some snags.  The first concern is that I'm seeing a variety of errors -- the errors are not consistent.  One time, it said it could not find casper/vmlinuz.efi.  Another time it gave squashfs errors.  I downloaded a fresh copy of Ubuntu and tried it again, this time checking the media (USB stick) for bad blocks.  No errors.  I booted again and got to the choice to install or try Ubuntu.  Progress!  But now it alternates between hanging and puking error messages.

[image: Ubuntu install Error puke]

Any guidance most welcome!

Comment: Dells usually just work. UEFI or BIOS boot?  Dell XPS 8900 i7-6700 pcie_aspm=off (also: Asus X555UB)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760257/ubuntu-16-04-failed-clean-install-on-new-hard-drive

Comment: I'm doing a legacy boot from BIOS.  Booting from UEFI gets nowhere.

Comment: I see from the link kindly provided by oldfred that Bhikkhu Subhuti is describing the same behavior I've seen when attempting to boot using UEFI.  I'll give it a shot and report back tomorrow.

Comment: Another thread mentions you must have RAID off and AHCI on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/761673/install-16-04-on-dell-xps-13 Dell just released new XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04, previous used 14.04. But Dell releases Sputnik drivers updates for anything they have that is not yet standard. By next release of Ubuntu all of Sputnik is usually included in Ubuntu. Two mega-threads, issues are usually common by vendor: Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Xps 15 9550 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843
Dell Xps 15 9550   post 272 says 16.04 good
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301071